# Why does clean and build not reveal all exceptions?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Sometimes after doing a clean of the whole project it compiles ok. But then at some later point, a file that hasn't changed starts flagging a legimate compilation error. I've seen this occur on multiple projects?

Why does this happen?

Comment: i hope that when you clean all targets then automitically remove all links with libraries

Comment: For instance yesterday I renamed a file and updated places where it was referenced. It compiled and run ok yesterday following a clean. Today I compiled it and it had a compile error in a file where I had missed updating the reference.

Answer (score 0):

To get a complete project clean you have to delete all the derived data well. Use the Organizer, then select Projects and look for the Delete button on the right.